# Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

This is regarding defining routes using route attribute. I have two controllers

1st Controller

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Member/Login")]
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
{
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    return View();
}
```

2nd Controller

```
[Route("{CategoryURL}/{Keywords}")]
public ActionResult BrowseProducts(string CategoryURL, string Keywords)
{

}
```

I am getting below error If try to access URL xyz.net/Member/Login

**Multiple controller types were found that match the URL. This can happen if attribute routes on multiple controllers match the requested URL.
The request has found the following matching controller types:
XYZ.Controllers.AccountController
XYZ.Controllers.CoursesController**

I am aware that I have Optional Parameters for second controller, hence when I try to access xyz.net/Member/Login, it finds two action methods to go for and getting the Multiple controller error.

My question is, how could I fix this issue without changing my current Routings. I tried Order, Precedence but nothing worked out.

Comment: what are your routes defined in your Global.asax / App_Start ? Attribute routing is supported in MVC 5 predominantly. If you're using it, you need to register attribute routing in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

As I commented above, based on your elected tags you are using MVC 4 yet attribute routing is supported in MVC 5. If you really are in MVC 5, then the following reference would be very helpful for you:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/

Most importantly, it's crucial that when you register your routes you active attribute routing -->

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{ 
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

And also ensure you don't have any other routes being defined that could confict with the attributes you've elected to use.

Otherwise your selected attribute should work fine. Pretty simple application.

Comment: I have mentioned routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes(); in my route config. Things are working fine if I remove [Route("{CategoryURL}/{Keywords}")]. Hence, there is not issue in configuring routing.

Answer (score 0):

The web api constraints may also aply for what you are trying to accomplish

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions