# Multiple Controller Maches Url Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Why I a getting this exception ,I have read
 [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455686/multiple-controller-types-were-found-that-match-the-url-asp-net-mvc)
and this 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36621459/asp-net-webapi-multiple-controller-types-were-found-that-match-the-url) but no luck here is my code screenshot please help.

**Exception**

[image: **Exception**]

**Find Result**

[image: Find Result]

**Controller Action**

```
//====Inside OrderController=====//

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/order/saveOrder")]
    public long saveOrder(JObject dataModel)
    {



    }



    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/order/saveorderBitdesigner")]
    public bool saveorderBitdesignerData(JObject dataModel)

   {

   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is matching multiple controller types, not routes.

Check `AgencyPageHtmlController`.